# Deleting the contents from ttk.entry via button - Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, declaration, ttk

I am trying to clear an entry field, but for some reason this trivial exercise is bringing up a "NameError: name 'PartDesc' is not defined" message and it totally escapes me on where I am going wrong. I have tried shifting my _clear_text around but it still eludes me on where I am going wrong.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.font
from tkinter import ttk
import csv
from csv import DictReader
import sys
import os
import subprocess

tree_columns = ("Drawing", "Issue", "Document type")

class TFPP:

def __init__(self):
    self.tree = None
    self._setup_widgets()
    self._build_tree()
    self._clear_text()


def _setup_widgets(self):
    #this is the setup & layout for the top part of the application i.e. the textbox and buttons.
    frame1=ttk.Frame()
    frame1.pack(fill='both', expand=False)
    AmpicsLabel = ttk.Label(frame1,justify="left", anchor="s", text=("Ampics Number :"))
    SOentry=ttk.Entry(frame1,justify="left", width=15)#, sonumber)
    Searchbutton = ttk.Button(frame1,text="Search")#, command='do_a_search')
    AmpicsLabel.pack(side="left", padx=5)
    SOentry.pack(side="left", padx=5)
    Searchbutton.pack(side="right", padx=3, pady=1)

    frame2=ttk.Frame()
    frame2.pack(fill='both', expand=False)
    DescLabel = ttk.Label(frame2,justify="left", anchor="sw", text=("Part Description : "))
    PartDesc = ttk.Entry(frame2,justify="left", width=57)
    Resetbutton = ttk.Button(frame2,text="Reset", command=self._clear_text)

    DescLabel.pack(side="left", padx=5)
    PartDesc.pack(side="left", padx=5,pady=5)
    Resetbutton.pack(side="right", padx=3, pady=1)

    frame3=ttk.Frame()
    frame3.pack(fill='both', expand=False)
    Quitbutton = ttk.Button(frame3,text="Quit", command=app.destroy)
    Quitbutton.pack(side="right", padx=3, pady=1) 

    # this is the setup & layout for the drawing list part.
    container = ttk.Frame()
    container.pack(fill='both', expand=False)
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=tree_columns, show="headings")
    vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
    self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew', in_=container)
    vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns', in_=container)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


def _build_tree(self):
    for col in tree_columns:
        self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title(),
            command=lambda c=col: sortby(self.tree, c, 0))

        self.tree.column("Drawing",width=120,anchor="center", stretch="no")
        self.tree.column("Issue",width=75, anchor="center", stretch="no")
        self.tree.column("Document type",anchor="w",width=300)
        self.treeview=self.tree

def _clear_text(self):
    PartDesc.delete(0, end)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tkinter.Tk()
    app.title("Production Drawings")
    app.geometry("550x330")
    tfpp = TFPP()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: hint: `PartDesc` is a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a tk.StringVar() to store the contents of the Entry. You can get it by using the get() method and set it using the set() method. To clear it you would set it as so

```
self.my_string = tk.StringVar()
PartDesc = ttk.Entry(frame2, textvariable=self.my_string, justify="left", width=57)
self.my_string.set(‘test’)
```

Function:

```
def _clear_text(self):
     self.my_string.set(‘’)
```

You could do this or pass the tk.StringVar() through the function.